# How to add exception handling

Tags: c++, exception

Hi everyone I would like to add exception handling for a couple conditions. Parentheses mismatch when unstacking and and if the expression entered by the user doesn't start and end with #. Mostly just looking for pointers and tips for expression handling in a class and main not a solution.

Here's what I was thinking but its obviously not correct.
This is done in my infixtopost class and I have class invalidExp(){} declared in my header file.
The other exception I tried to handle in main checking the line of input from the user with
`if(line[0] != '#' || line[line.length()] != '#') throw "Invalid Expression"`
but it would skip over this line and when I put it in a try catch block the rest of the code couldn't exectue.

```
while (!op->isEmpty() && op->top() != '(') throw invalidExp();
{
    post.push_back(op->pop());

    if (!op->isEmpty())
    {
        op->pop();
    } //to remove ( from stack
}
```

`main:`

```
try{
    IntoPost *infix = new IntoPost(token.length());
    post = infix->inToPost(token);

    cout << post << "=";

    Evalexp *result = new Evalexp(post.length());
    result->evalExp(post);
    result->print();
}
catch (IntoPost::invalidExp){
    cout << "Exception: Invalid Expression" << endl;
}
```

Comment: `line[line.length()] != '#'` -> `line[line.length() - 1] != '#'` or even `line.back() != '#'`

Comment: It's probably good if you can edit the formatting on this to be more clear. It's hard to understand as is.

Answer (score 3):

As I understand your question, you want to declare some custom exception types to handle errors in a clean way. Thats good and the following code will be an example of how this can be done. It's all just an example, to show what is possible.

## 0: Understanding throw

You can read more about throw [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw). But in general you can throw anything. `throw 1;` will throw an int for example. Your example `throw "Invalid Expression"` will throw a `const char*`. Usually you want to throw an object of a class that inherits from `std::exception`.

## 1: Declare a class for each type of exception you need to handle

It's good practice to let them extend from std::exception. In the constructor I usually create the exception message and pass it to the constructor of `std::exception`. So the following are just examples:

```
class ExceptionA : public std::exception {
  public:
    ExceptionA() : std::exception("Case A occurred!") { }
};

class ExceptionB : public std::exception {
  public:
    static string CreateMessage(int x, int y) {
        // You can create a custom exception message here
    }
    
    ExceptionB(int x, int y) : std::exception(ExceptionB::CreateMessage(x, y)) {}
};
```

As you see in `ExceptionB` it's totally fine to attach additional data to your exception. This will help you to create a more specific exception message.

## 2: Sorround your code with a try-multicatch

You can read more about this [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/try_catch)
It means, you can use multiple catch-blocks for each try-block.

```
void foo() {
    try {
        // Calcultion starts here
        // Now you get unexpected input or something like this and signal it by throwing an exception.
        if(errorCondition) { throw ExceptionA(); }

        // Something else might happen here, so you throw the other type of exception
        // in this example ExceptionB also takes two custom parameters.
        if(otherErrorCondition) { throw ExceptionB(x, y); }
    }
    catch(ExceptionA &e) {
        // Handle an occurence of Exception A
    }
    catch(ExceptionB &e) {
        // Handle an occurence of Exception B
    }
    catch(std::exception &e) {
        // Handle an occurrence of any other exceptions STL-components migth throw for example std::range_error
    }
    catch(...) {
        // Handle the occurrence of any other thrown ... things. This will also catch things like throw 1, but usually you don't need this.
    }
}
```

Here the order of the catch-blocks is important!

## 3: Enjoy clean exception handling!

I hope this answers your question!